Deep Neural Network Concatenation problem
I am looking to concatenate two neural networks. But after building the first one, an input warning occurs. At the end, this ValueError occurs.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-516cf02e1bd0> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 combinedInput = concatenate([network_1.output, network_2.output])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py in _get_node_attribute_at_index(self, node_index, attr, attr_name)
    283         """
    284         if not self._inbound_nodes:
--> 285             raise ValueError(
    286                 f"The layer {self.name} has never been called "
    287                 f"and thus has no defined {attr_name}."

ValueError: The layer sequential has never been called and thus has no defined output.

What does it mean by no defined output?
I tried compiling the two networks but still don't work (That's why I used # on compile line)
The entire code is given below.
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input ,concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_percentage_error

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
housing = fetch_california_housing()
print(housing['feature_names'])

X = housing['data']
y = housing['target']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.7, random_state=42)

#Network 1
network_1 = Sequential()
network_1.add(Dense(units = 4, input_dim = X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
network_1.add(Dense(units = 4, activation='relu'))
network_1.add(Dense(units = 4, activation='relu'))
network_1.add(Dense(units = 4, activation='relu'))
#network_1.compile(loss= 'mean_squared_error', optimizer= Adam, metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/layers/core/dense.py:87: UserWarning: Do not pass an `input_shape`/`input_dim` argument to a layer. When using Sequential models, prefer using an `Input(shape)` object as the first layer in the model instead.
  super().__init__(activity_regularizer=activity_regularizer, **kwargs)
#network 2
network_2 = Sequential()
network_2.add(Dense(units = 16, input_dim= , activation='relu'))
network_2.add(Dense(units = 16, activation='relu'))
#network_2.compile(loss= 'mean_squared_error', optimizer= Adam, metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

combinedInput = concatenate([network_1.output, network_2.output])


That's a warning, not an error. You do not seem to have any problem.

The error occurs because network_1 and network_2 are not yet built. In keras, layers in a sequential model are not instantiated until the model is called on some input data. when you try to access the .output attribute of a sequential model you need to build or called it manually before accessing it. Please refer to this gist.
